# Check character differences in a string using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, char

In SQL, I have got a column "MyString" representing a string of characters where each character represent different statuses in the lifecycle of a product.

The objective is to write a SQL code which will extract automatically from "MyString" the current status of the product, the previous status of the product as well as their index.

To simulate the context, here is some code:

```
DECLARE @MyString nvarchar(100) = 'AAABBC'

SELECT      
SUBSTRING(@MyString,1,1) as first_status,
CHARINDEX('b',@MyString) AS second_status_index,
SUBSTRING(@MyString,4,1) as second_status,
CHARINDEX('c',@MyString) AS third_status_index;
```

The idea is to automate this query so that I can re-use it for a number of records but not sure if it's possible.

Expected output:

| first_status | second_status_index | second_status | third_status_index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | B | 6 |

Comment: IS there a question?

Comment: How to automate this query

Comment: What do you mean by "automate"? Have a job or bot run it for you?

Comment: I want to automatically find the second status, whatever this is and return its index. In the example above I used CHARINDEX('b',@MyString) but I would basically need to check for the next status that differs from the first one.

Comment: Avoid doing data processing in SQL as much as you can. I would strongly recommend you use the database to store and retrieve data only, and not to do smart things. If you go this path, the queries are going to become prohibitely slow.